MLflow Docker on Azure: Error Saving Artifacts to Blob Storage (MissingRequiredHeader)
I'm deploying an MLflow server on Azure using a Docker image. The MLflow server URL is accessible, but I'm encountering an issue when trying to save artifacts in Azure Blob Storage. I receive the following error:
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified

Some additional info: I'm using Azure Blob Storage for storing artifacts. The connection to the SQL backend works fine.
My launch.sh script (executed by the Dockerfile):
mlflow server \
--backend-store-uri "$MLFLOW_BACKEND_STORE_URI" \
--default-artifact-root "$MLFLOW_SERVER_DEFAULT_ARTIFACT_ROOT" \
--host "$MLFLOW_SERVER_HOST" \
--port "$MLFLOW_SERVER_PORT" \
--workers "$MLFLOW_SERVER_WORKERS"

After pushing the image to Azure, Ive created an Azure web app with the necessary env variables like:
MLFLOW_SERVER_DEFAULT_ARTIFACT_ROOT="https://$STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME.blob.core.windows.net/$STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME?$SAS_TOKEN"


AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;AccountName=$STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME;AccountKey=$AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY;BlobEndpoint=https://$STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME.blob.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://$STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME.file.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://$STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME.queue.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://$STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME.table.core.windows.net/"



requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified

The above error occurs when MLflow is attempting to access Azure Blob Storage but is missing some required authentication headers or is not correctly configured to authenticate with the storage account.
Make sure the SAS token is in correct format and with required permission((rwl for read, write, list) and headers.
In my side, I also got the same error:
Error:

In my environment, header is wrong when I added correct header with request it created successfully.
Request:
PUT https://<storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net/<conatiner name>/<blob name>?sp=racwdli&st=2024-09-09T11:01:06Z&se=2024-09-09T19:01:06Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=X9dl96r6waxxxxxxD
x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob


Reference:
Put Blob (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn

hanks for the reply! :) I’m not sure this applies in my case, though. From what I understand, in MLflow, when you configure the artifact root with a SAS token, the internal logic or the Azure SDK handles the necessary headers automatically. Is there a way to explicitly add custom headers in MLflow, or would this be handled another way?

Please add the code in the question which you tried so far?

I've just added some information about the deployment

Can you share the document which you referring?

I pushed all the files in a github repo : https://github.com/sbendimerad/mlops_series/tree/main/step2_docker_mlflow_azure and this is the doc i refered to it : https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking/artifacts-stores.html
Thanks

As of know, I don't have any experience in mlflow will check right back to you.
